# Cypress for Flutter (android)

Tags: flutter, testing, integration-testing, end-to-end

Is there a best practice variant for end-to-end testing in Flutter that is like Cypress or works emulator based?
It should cover the app for Android and not the webapp or PWA.

I look forward to your input!

Comment: You cannot use Cypress (which is designed to test applications running in a browser). But you could simply go with [integration testing](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/integration-tests) (see also [this cookbook](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction)) which basically, like Cypress, allow you to "fake" user actions and execute tests in the emulator/device.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed I have written one recently. The features are somehow inspired by Cypress, so you will feel very familiar to use it if you know Cypress or other modern testing frameworks :)

Link: https://github.com/fzyzcjy/flutter_convenient_test
(With 1-minute video intro included)

One-sentence feature introduction: Write and debug tests easily, with full action history, time travel, screenshots, rapid re-execution, video records, interactivity, isolation and more.